# CMS which allows non-technical users to extend the schema 

Tags: database, content-management-system

I'm working at a school and want to setup a web-based school information system to replace the 'spreadsheet spaghetti' currently used. The systems I've looked at just don't have the flexibility I'm after. A particular requirement is that the 'system' allows non-admin users to:

- add fields to existing tables (most systems allow this)
- add completely new tables (not seen that capability yet)
- and then the capture/presentation forms just work from templates setup by admin users - no HTML/CSS required for those non-admin users

I've looked at specific school information systems, and I've also looked at systems to generate GUI for MySQL databases. I reckon I need something in the middle - a generic CMS which will handle the website side of things with nice database management GUI built in.

Anyone seen anything like this ... my extensive Googling hasn't come up with one yet.

Cheers,

Colin.

Answer (score 0):

[eZ Publish](http://share.ez.no/) delivers exactly that, but generally this ability is only provided to Admin or Expert users because for example allowing a user to remove a table would cause data to be lost.
That system uses an EAV-based schema. In other words it stores the schema definition as metadata.  Anyway, the result is that users can be permitted to alter the content classes and their attributes i.e. they can create the equivalent of new tables and new fields (technical admins can also add invented attribute/field-types). But the underlying system schema never changes.
When the new 'tables' (content classes) have been defined the system uses their definition to automatically create default screens for creation, viewing and managing the data in those new tables. You (the site-owner/developer) can override the default appearance of those pages via CSS and HTML template changes.
If you have more questions, I'm sure the forums at the above URL will respond quickly.